# Naive Bayes Rule related question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> I stucked at the following Baye's rule related probability question.
>   Suppose $X_1,X_2, Z$ be discrete random variables with probability mass function $p(\cdot)$.  I was wondering under what condition, the following equality holds
>
> $$p(x_2|x_1,z)p(x_1,z) =?= p(x_2|x_1)p(x_1|z)p(z)$$

Here is my thinking:
$p(x_1,z) = p(x_1|z)p(z)$ by definition.

But when can I say 
$p(x_2|x_1,z) = p(x_2|x_1)$ ? I was guessing the independence of $Z$ and $X_2$ but not quite sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's when $X_2$ and $Z$ are [**conditionally independent**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence) given $X_1$.

$$X_2\bot Z\mid X_1 \\\Updownarrow\\\mathsf P(X_2=x_2\cap Z=z\mid X_1=x_1) \;=\; \mathsf P(X_2=x_2\mid X_1=x_1)\;\mathsf P(Z=z\mid X_1=z_1)
\\ \Updownarrow
\\ \mathsf P(X_2=x_2\mid X_1=x_1, Z=z)= \mathsf P(X_2=x_2\mid X_1=x_1)\qquad\qquad(\ast)
$$

It's the statement that the conditional distributions of $X_2\mid_{X_1}$ and $Z\mid_{X_1}$ behave independently, even though the distributions of $X_2$ and $Z$ *may* not.

---

$(\ast)$ assumes that $\mathsf P(Z=z\mid X_1=x_1)\neq 0$

Comment: Thanks for reply @Graham Kemp,  But I still a little bit confused. Could you say more words about How to get $p(x_2|x_1,z) = p(x_2|x_1)$ from the conditionally independence?

Comment: @Fianra The same way you would obtain $\mathsf P(A=a\mid B=b)=\mathsf P(A=a)$ from unconditional independence.